# Can I stop the batteries in a device from draining by taking out just one?

Tags: batteries

I bought a blood pressure monitor and at the moment I'm taking the batteries out after each use.  I'll probably end up buying rechargeable batteries and not worry about taking the batteries out, but I'm curious to know if I need to take out all of the batteries to keep them from draining or if I can just take out one.  My (basic) understanding of electronics leads me to think that as long as the batteries are in series, I should only need to take out one to break any kind of circuit that might be present.

Comment: Likely you’re correct, and they are in series. Taking one out would break the circuit. If they’re in parallel, no.

Comment: It's probably easier just to stick a plastic strip in between the two batteries

Comment: A well designed device should not drain the batteries excessively. Of all the battery powered devices that I own, only one is worth my trouble to remove the battery. I have a photo flash meter that uses a non-standard (expensive) battery. I don't use it very often so the battery was often dead the next time I went to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that removing one of a series connected set of cells will break the circuit.

More than likely the unit goes into deep sleep mode when off so it is not worth the effort. If you have access to a multimeter you can set it to the lowest mA range and measure the current while it is asleep by connecting the meter in series with the cells somehow. If you find the datasheet for the batteries you will get a figure for capacity in mAh at a certain drainage rate. Divide this by your current reading to estimate the number of hours.

$$ h = \frac {mAh}{mA} $$

You will get far more than this because the standby current is not stressing the chemistry.

Comment: My basic rule for designing battery-powered equipment is that if the current so consumed is less than the self-discharge current of the battery, then I probably don't have to worry about it.  This doesn't get you off the hook for poorly designed equipment, though -- which is why the suggested check with a multimeter is a good idea.